# why do i get PearsonRConstantInputWarning when using stats.boxcox_normmax?

Tags: python, linear-regression, normalization, transformation, skew

i'm trying to transform my data and lessen the skewness of some features with `astats.boxcox_normmax` to find the best value for boxcox.

```
### Transforming with boxcox normmax
for field in list(all_skewed_features) :
    all_data[field]=boxcox1p(all_data[field],stats.boxcox_normmax(all_data[field]+1))
```

but I get this error:

```
PearsonRConstantInputWarning:
An input array is constant; the correlation coefficent is not defined.
```

it's interesting that the first time I run the code I have this error but by running it another time I don't have any error.
is it right to transform data two times?

Comment: I get the same issue intermitently with the same data on `scipy.stats.pearsonr()`